# Bootstrap with multiple columns length doesn't fit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms

I really don't know why this is happening? Input form lines length doesn't fit.

I'm sure it has to be something really easy, but I don't know why.

This is the simple code as you can see nothing special:

[image]

Current code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!--<script src="program.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
<div class ="container">
  <h1>Test </h1>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
  </div>
 ...
     </div> 
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Finally I solverd using with <div class="form-group col-md-12"> Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You did not wrap all the form elements in a `<div class="form-row">`.

Corrected:

```html
<div class ="container">
  <h1>Test </h1>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
    </div>
  </div>
 ...
</div>
```